# Python fill matrix with content from file (integers)

Tags: python

I have a program that opens and reads a text file.

The text file will always be in the following format with 3 columns and a unspecified amount of rows:

1234,0,5

1235,5,10

1236,10,15

…………

………….

I have successfully initialized a matrix with its size depending on the amount of lines in the file.

But how can I now fill the matrix with each integer in the correct column and row?

```
def main():
    f = open(text.txt, "r")
    f1 = f.readlines()

    # matrix 
    w = 3
    Matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in f1]
```

[image]

Comment: Is numpy accepted or you are looking for raw python solution?

Comment: My guess would be that everything that works is accepted :)

Comment: You want to iterate over the lines, split by “,”, and assign the results of parsing the string as an integer to the rows of the matrix. I’m guessing that you’re not allowed to use `numpy.loadtxt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it, you just need to use the data you have in your `f1` variable.

```
def main():
    with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
        f1 = f.readlines()

    # matrix 
    Matrix = [[int(x) for x in y.split(",")] for y in f1]
```

That said, if you're okay with using other libraries many can do the work for you.

e.g.:
numpy:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.loadtxt("test.txt", dtype="int", delimiter=",")
```

pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

matrix = pd.read_csv("test.txt")
```